# Am I too old to do an MS in Finance?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, career-path, business-school

I want to do a Masters in Finance. I am from India. I am 30 years old. I have seen that most people in masters programs in finance are less than 25 year old. I also don't have much in terms of corporate work experience. I have degrees in engineering and a 2 year diploma in management with a specialization in Finance. From what I know, masters programs in finance in the American and European business schools are mostly meant for those fresh out of an undergraduate degree. I feel that if I finish an MS in Finance I will be competing with people much younger than me for entry level jobs and therefore will be at a disadvantage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general answer for all such questions is no, you aren't too old. Even if you were 60.

Actually, masters programs are *meant* for qualified candidates, not for some age group. The fact that most people continue through schooling without breaks explains the age distribution in graduate degrees, not some hidden rules and not market forces.

Your admissibility will depend on your past record and how well it fits entrance requirements. After that, your success depends on you.

Nor do I believe that you will suffer age discrimination entering the workforce for such a small difference in ages. Laws may govern this in some places. But, again, you will be viewed in the marketplace by your accomplishments, not your age.

There are exceptions, of course, since not everyone is reasonable or just, but enough people do the right thing that you should be fine.